# connection error py2neo, python 3, win10 64-bit

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, windows-10, 64-bit, py2neo

I'm trying to connect to the Neo4j server using the tutorial commands however I get the following error:

```
from py2neo import Graph
g = Graph(host='localhost', port=7687)
tx = g.begin()
a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
tx.create(a)
b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)
tx.create(ab)
tx.commit()
print(g.exists(ab))
```

> Blockquote

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    140             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 141                 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    142 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     82     if err is not None:
---> 83         raise err
     84 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     72                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 73             sock.connect(sa)
     74             return sock
```

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    600                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 601                                                   chunked=chunked)
    602 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    356         else:
--> 357             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    358 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1238         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1240 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1284             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1286 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1233             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1235 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    963             if self.auto_open:
--> 964                 self.connect()
    965             else:

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    165     def connect(self):
--> 166         conn = self._new_conn()
    167         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    149             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 150                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    151
```

> NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\http.py in request(self, method, url, fields, headers, **urlopen_kw)
    188         try:
--> 189             return self._http.request(method, url, fields, headers, **urlopen_kw)
    190         except MaxRetryError:

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py in request(self, method, url, fields, headers, **urlopen_kw)
     69                                             headers=headers,
---> 70                                             **urlopen_kw)
     71 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py in request_encode_body(self, method, url, fields, headers, encode_multipart, multipart_boundary, **urlopen_kw)
    147 
--> 148         return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    667                                 release_conn=release_conn, body_pos=body_pos,
--> 668                                 **response_kw)
    669 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    667                                 release_conn=release_conn, body_pos=body_pos,
--> 668                                 **response_kw)
    669 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    667                                 release_conn=release_conn, body_pos=body_pos,
--> 668                                 **response_kw)
    669 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    638             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 639                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    640             retries.sleep()

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    387         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 388             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    389
```

> MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost:7687', port=None):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: /db/data/transaction (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it',))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-4018ad364426> in <module>()
      1 tx = g.begin()
      2 a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
----> 3 tx.create(a)
      4 b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
      5 ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\graph.py in create(self, subgraph)
    933             raise TypeError("No method defined to create object %r" % subgraph)
    934         else:
--> 935             create(self)
    936 
    937     def degree(self, subgraph):

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\types.py in __db_create__(self, tx)
    331         statement = "\n".join(reads + writes + ["RETURN %s LIMIT 1" % ", ".join(returns)])
    332         tx.entities.append(returns)
--> 333         list(tx.run(statement, parameters))
    334 
    335     def __db_degree__(self, tx):

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\graph.py in __iter__(self)
   1110 
   1111     def __iter__(self):
-> 1112         while self.forward():
   1113             yield self._current
   1114 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\graph.py in forward(self, amount)
   1169         fetch = self._result.fetch
   1170         while moved != amount:
-> 1171             new_current = fetch()
   1172             if new_current is None:
   1173                 break

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\graph.py in fetch(self)
    778         """
    779         try:
--> 780             return next(self.result_iterator)
    781         except StopIteration:
    782             return None

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\api.py in records(self)
    435         hydrate = self.value_system.hydrate
    436         zipper = self.zipper
--> 437         keys = self.keys()
    438         records = self._records
    439         while records:

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\api.py in keys(self)
    425         """
    426         while self._keys is None and self.online():
--> 427             self.fetch()
    428         return self._keys
    429 

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\api.py in fetch(self)
    407         """
    408         if self.online():
--> 409             return self._session.fetch()
    410         else:
    411             return 0

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\http.py in fetch(self)
    295 
    296     def fetch(self):
--> 297         return self.sync()
    298 
    299     def sync(self):

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\http.py in sync(self)
    306         count = 0
    307         try:
--> 308             response = self.post(ref, {"statements": self._statements}, expected=(OK, CREATED))
    309             if response.status == 201:
    310                 location_path = urlsplit(response.headers["Location"]).path

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\http.py in post(self, ref, json, expected)
    210             headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    211             json = json_dumps(json).encode('utf-8')
--> 212         rs = self.request("POST", self.path + ref, headers=self._headers, body=json)
    213         if rs.status not in expected:
    214             raise_error(self.uri, rs.status, rs.data)

~\Anaconda3\envs\wavelength\lib\site-packages\py2neo\http.py in request(self, method, url, fields, headers, **urlopen_kw)
    189             return self._http.request(method, url, fields, headers, **urlopen_kw)
    190         except MaxRetryError:
--> 191             raise ServiceUnavailable("Cannot send %r request to %r" % (method, url))
    192 
    193     def get_json(self, ref):
```

> ServiceUnavailable: Cannot send 'POST' request to
>   '/db/data/transaction'

Comment: UPDATE: tried specifying localhost in IPv4, got the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093488/neo4j-python-driver-service-unavailable

Answer (score 4):

Solved this, a very noob error on my part - I had to initialise the server before running the above commands.  Apologies for "crying wolf" )

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not authenticating correctly. You might try the following:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "your password"))
with driver.session() as session:
        with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
            for record in tx.run("your cypher query"):
                {process the response}
```

Comment: I followed this tut with default settings - it doesn't mention authentication settings http://py2neo.org/2.0/intro.html#getting-connected

Comment: addition:  I tried to run a query as per above and got the error "Failed to establish connection to ('localhost', 7687)"

Comment: Check the port, it may not be 7687. The choices are usually 7687 or 11002 for bolt connections. If you use Neo4j Desktop, this is visible when you start the database and then click the Manage button.  

see also https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/ports/

Answer (score 0):

I am using Neo4j Community 4.0 with the latest official Neo4j Bolt driver and was getting the same error.

In order to get rid of it, I had to uncomment the following setting in `neo4j.conf` and re-start the Neo4j service:

```
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

Not sure why Neo4J server considers the connection from a local driver session to be a remote connection, but it worked for me.